# How can we execute selenium automation script, without Visual Studio?

Tags: selenium-webdriver-c#

I am automating a web application using Selenium WebDriver in C# using  Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019.

Here is my question: how can we execute our automation script without Visual Studio?

I created a batch file to execute the script and we are mentioning the path of "vstest.console.exe" in the batch file like:

> "C:\xxx\xxx\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"

I want to execute my automation script on any machine without installing Visual Studio. Is it possible?

My batch file code looks like this:

> --- batch file code start here ---
>
> set test_runner="Driver:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
>
> set
> test_dlls="Driver:\Users\XXXXX\source\repos\XXXXX_AutomationScripts\XXXXXxx_AutomationScripts\bin\Debug\XXXXXX_AutomationScripts.dll"
>
> set tests="Smoke_XXX_Search_XXXX"
>
> %test_runner% %test_dlls% /tests:%tests%
>
> Taskkill /IM conhost.exe /F
>
> -- end here

I copy "vstest.console.exe" into some other location in my system and given that path like:

> Driver:\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe

Now I am getting an exception like:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///D:\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Hi @Surya. Welcome to the community!
Please do mentioned what all you have tried, any error occur when you ask any question to seek help. 
Lastly, do accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sure, Narendra I will mention my code.

Comment: Although you've copied over vstest.console.exe, have you also copied all of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **YES**.

- We can execute selenium automation script without Visual Studio

**How to execute without Visual Studio ?**

- Considering, Selenium pre-requisites should be in-place already
- **Pre-requisite** :

  - Check Java installed
  - Unpack Selenium RC.
  - Open a cmd.exe window and go to the directory containing the Selenium Server (selenium-remote-control-1.0.1\selenium-server-1.0.1)
  - **Run the command** below:

> java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox"
> "http://22.5.150.62" "C:\mytest\mytest.html" "C:\mytest\results.html"

- This should run your test suite in Firefox and write the results to the html file.
- You will need to change the "http://22.5.150.62" argument to your own server (this might just be localhost / 127.0.0.1)
- **Interpreter** :

  - Understand VSCode is an interpreter and helps you to write code
  - Anytime you can use any other freeware like Eclipse, SublimeText etc
- **Execution through batch file**:

  - As you have created batch file only barrier I can see that **you can use it on Windows** which you might be aware
- **Dependancy on VSCode** :

  - From details you shared I have not figured out anywhere you have any tight binding with VSCode or using any of the default library [Please let me know if you have already & missed to mention]
  - Even if you have any dependancy/library from VSCode while creating batch file you can explicitly mentioned specific dependancy **so you doesn't have to have VSCode installed on machine**

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the location of vstest.console.exe as an argument on command
that you run.

See this answer for Windows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/653587/2252076